# How to add CoreData.framework to existing xcode 4.6.2 project

Tags: xcode

I have been struggling adding CoreData.framework to my existing xcode 4.6.2 project. I googled and all the answer I got is by control-click on frameworks folder and Select Add -> Existing Frameworks. This "Existing Framework" is not in the menu.

Answer (score 13):

Select your project and then select your target, click on the Tab 'Build phases'. Open the section 'Link Binary with Libraries' and click on the `+` sign.

[image: Xcode]

Comment: Thanks a lot guys. Je suis désolé as I am unable to vote up as it requires whooping 15 reputation !

Comment: Thanks a lot guys. Je suis désolé as I am unable to vote up as it requires whooping 15 reputation !

Answer (score 0):

In Xcode, select your target in the navigator. Click the Build Phases tab. Click the add button under the link with binary box, and select CoreData.framework, if its not there, you might reinstall Xcode.

Comment: Thanks a lot guys. Je suis désolé as I am unable to vote up as it requires whooping 15 reputation !